# Prove that $x^2 y+ y^2 z + z^2x ≥ 2(x + y + z) − 3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Let $x$, $y$ and $z$ be positive real numbers such that $xy + yz + zx = 3xyz$. Prove that $x^2 y+ y^2 z + z^2x ≥ 2(x + y + z) − 3$

This question is from BMO 2014.
My working:

By AM-GM inequaluity,
  $$x^2 y+ y^2 z + z^2x ≥ 3xyz=xy+yz+zx$$
So now I need to prove that
$$xy+yz+zx\ge2(x+y+z)-3$$
To prove this do I need the relation $xy + yz + zx = 3xyz$?
Need help.

Comment: what is BMO? and 2014?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I guess BMO is British Mathematical Olympiad, and 2014 is the 2,014-th year in the Gregorian calendar. As last inequality is inhomogeneous in $x$, $y$ and $z$ it cannot be proved without some non-trivial assumptions on these variables.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner BMO stands for Balkan Mathematics Olympiad and 2014 is a year in the 21st century, followed by 2015 and preceded  by 2013.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Can you help me with this inequality?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown What do you mean by non trivial assumptions?

Comment: Assumptions beyond "$x$, $y$, $z$ are positive".

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown $x\ge y\ge z$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x=\frac{1}{a}$, $y=\frac{1}{b}$ and $z=\frac{1}{c}.$

Thus, $a+b+c=3$ and we need to prove that
$$a^2c+b^2a+c^2b\geq2abc(ab+ac+bc)-3a^2b^2c^2$$ opr
$$\frac{(a+b+c)^3(a^2c+b^2a+c^2b)}{27}\geq\frac{2abc(ab+ac+bc)(a+b+c)}{3}-3a^2b^2c^2$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^5c+a^4b^2+3a^4c^2+3a^3b^3+3a^4bc-12a^3b^2c-11a^3c^2b+12a^2b^2c^2)\geq0,$$
which is true by Schur and AM-GM.

The Schur inequality is the following.

Let $x$, $y$ and $z$ be positive numbers.

Prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}(x^3-x^2y-x^2z+xyz)\geq0.$$
Now, let $x=bc$, $y=ac$ and $z=ab$.

Thus, $$\sum_{cyc}(a^3b^3-a^3b^2c-a^3c^2b+a^2b^2c^2)\geq0$$ or
$$3\sum_{cyc}(a^3b^3-a^3b^2c-a^3c^2b+a^2b^2c^2)\geq0.$$
Also, by AM-GM $$\sum_{cyc}a^5c\geq\sum_{cyc}a^4bc$$,
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^4b^2+a^4c^2)\geq2\sum_{cyc}a^4bc.$$
Thus, by Schur again
$$6\sum_{cyc}(a^4bc-a^3b^2c-a^3c^2b+a^2b^2c^2)\geq0.$$
Hence, it remains to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}(2a^4c^2-3a^3b^2c-2a^3c^2b+3a^2b^2c^2)\geq0,$$
which is obvious by the $uvw$ method.

Another way.

By C-S
$$\sum_{cyc}x^2y=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{y}\sum_{cyc}x^2y\geq\frac{1}{3}(x+y+z)^2\geq2(x+y+z)-3,$$
where the last inequality it's just $$(x+y+z-3)^2\geq0.$$
Done!

Comment: What is 'Schur'?

Comment: Would you please tell me what is Schur?

Comment: THanks for writing in detail.

Comment: How did you simplify the original expression to $$a^2c+b^2a+c^2b\geq2abc(ab+ac+bc)-3a^2b^2c^2$$?

Comment: Sorry but I am a bit weak in manipulating expressions.

Comment: Oh! Got that now

Comment: @a m i t y a s Ask your questions. I am ready to explain all step.

Comment: No, got every bit of it. Thank you

Comment: But you have to simplify a lot here! And you do not have that much time in olympiads!

Comment: @a m i t y a s I killed your inequality during nine minutes. I think you also can do it.

Comment: Yes...but I will wait for some time before accepting it!

Comment: @a m i t y a s The last inequality we can prove by uvw. See here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h278791 It's the easiest way I think.

Comment: @a m i t y a s I have found something easy. See now.

Comment: Thank you for your kind effort!

Comment: @a m i t y a s You are welcome! Did you see my second solution?

Comment: Yes, two great proofs in one great post!

Comment: Suddenly another solution has flashed in my head which i am posting here. I would be glad if u kindly comment on that.

Comment: @a m i t y a s OK. I wait.

Comment: I have posted it

Answer (score 5):

Given, $xy+yz+zx \ge 3xyz$
$$\Rightarrow 3=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{z}$$ 
Now $$x^2y+y^2z+z^2x\ge2(x+y+z)-3$$
$$\Rightarrow x^2y+y^2z+z^2x+3\ge2(x+y+z)$$
Now
$$x^2y+y^2z+z^2x+3=x^2y+y^2z+z^2x+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{z}$$
$$=\sum_{cyc} \frac{x^2y^2+1}{y}$$
$$\ge \sum_{cyc} 2x$$
Done!

Comment: @a m i t y a s Nice! +1.

Comment: Thanks! It feels great when appreciated! Specially by stalwarts like you!